# Switching to HasMany() and getting Sequence contains no matching element error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

I'm in a project where the entities were using an extra class to map the relationship between them, example:

```
public class MainEnt 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MainEntAnotherEnt> AnotherEnts{get;set;}
}

public class AnotherEnt 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class MainEntAnotherEnt
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MainEntId{ get; set; }
    public int AnotherEntId{ get; set; }
}
```

The project also uses auto migrations, so the MainEntAnotherEnt table is created explicitly in one of the migrations.

```
        CreateTable(
               "dbo.MainEntAnotherEnt",
               c => new
               {
                   Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                   MainEntId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                   AnotherEntId = c.Int(nullable: false),
               })
               .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Id })
               .ForeignKey("dbo.AnotherEnt", t => t.AnotherEntId)
               .ForeignKey("dbo.MainEnt", t => t.MainEntId)
               .Index(t => t.MainEntId)
               .Index(t => t.AnotherEntId);
```

I want to change this approach so we get rid of the MainEntAnotherEnt class, and we can do it using mapping, so I made these changes:

```
public class MainEnt 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AnotherEnt> AnotherEnts{get;set;}
}

public class AnotherEnt 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MainEnt> MainEnt {get;set;}
}


   modelBuilder.Entity<MainEnt >()
            .HasMany(m => m.AnotherEnts)
            .WithMany(a => a.MainEnt)
            .Map(ma =>
            {
                ma.MapLeftKey("MainEntId");
                ma.MapRightKey("AnotherEntId");
                ma.ToTable("MainEntAnotherEnt");
            });
```

But I'm getting the error:

> [InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element]
>      System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +472
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.d__70.MoveNext() +471
>      System.Linq.d__22`3.MoveNext() +355
>      System.Linq.d__63`1.MoveNext() +79
>      System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +504
>      System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +70
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.FindAssociationTypePairs(ICollection`1 entityTypePairs) +862
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(ModelMetadata source, ModelMetadata target, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion) +222
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion) +588
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.IsModelOutOfDate(XDocument model, DbMigration lastMigration) +72
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId) +342
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration) +609
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +609
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +116
>      System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +156
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +71
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +482
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +174
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +273
>      System.Data.Entity.Database.Initialize(Boolean force) +80

Any guidance with how to fix this will be very appreciate it!

Comment: Normally for the many-to-many implementation without linking entity requires the linking table to consist of *just* the two FK's set up as a composite PK. Your .map statement would be correct in that case. Try altering your MaintEntAnotherEnt table defintion to remove the existing PK and set up the 2 FK as a composite PK. Normally the joining entity is only needed if you want additional fields in the association. (typically things like audit fields.)

Comment: I edited my question and added how the linking table is been created in one of the migrations, I change the primary key to be composited `.PrimaryKey(t => new { t.DemoMaterialId, t.AudienceId })`   I think the issued is related with the fact that the table was created using the linking table, and now it's created using the mapping, since I'm not really familiar how auto migrations work, I don't know if I should add another migration dropping the table? I already tried run the add-migration command but I got the same exact error.